# Two stage compiling fails while single stage succeeds

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, g++

I am trying to compile a simple Antlr4 project. When I do it in single g++ command, it compiles successfully. However, when I compile and link separately, it fails.

Single stage compilation (**succeeds**):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra *.cpp -L. -l antlr4-runtime -I/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime -. -o exec
```

Two stage (**fails**: cannot link properly to antlr library and gives a lot of undefined reference errors):

```
main: $(OBJS)
          g++ -L. -l antlr4-runtime $^ -o exec
%.o: %.cpp
          g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/local/include/antlr4-runtime -I. -c $<
```

I wonder why linking fails in the latter case, while it has similar linking options to single stage compiling.

Comment: `"it fails"` isn't a very helpful problem description.  Please provide any error message(s) as text verbatim. Also note that among other things your `%.o: %.cpp` rule compiles and links to build a file named `exec` -- *not* a single `.o` file.  Indeed, your `main: $(OBJS)` rule also creates a file named `exec` *not* `main`.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typos in the question and clarified fail.

Comment: You still haven't shown the error message(s) from the linker.  It would also be helpful to show the complete makefile to clarify other details: e.g. what is the value of `OBJS` and how is it set etc.?

Comment: Actually I noticed if I link by "gcc *.o -L. -l antlr" it works, but if I put *.o in the end "gcc -L. -l antlr *.o", it does not work.